# Determine the value of the following definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have an integral defined from -4 to 4 f(x)dx = 4

What is

f(x)-2dx =

I have no Idea really how to go about this. I've tried googling it. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the value of $\int^4_{-4}(f(x)-2)dx$ is, given $\int^4_{-4}f(x)dx=4$?

Comment: I guess so, I'm doing the number on this program called MapleTA and it 's written as f(x) - 2dx not (f(x) -2)dx, 

But could you explain (f(x)-2)dx to me, knowing this program, that's probably what it's asking...

Comment: Hint:
You can use the linearity of the integral, i.e. the fact that:
$\int(f(x)+g(x))dx=\int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx \\$
.

Comment: I don't have a g(x) though :S.

Comment: Yes you do. Only its constant, so $x$ does not appear in it.

Comment: I tried doing 4 - 2 = 2 and It says it's wrong lol.

Comment: I suggest you read up on integration rules: http://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the linearity$$\int_{-4}^4(f(x)-2)dx=\int_{-4}^4f(x)dx-\int_{-4}^42dx=4-[2(4)-2(-4)]=4-(8+8)=-12$$